# Atom.io - Java Compiling fine, Runtime - Class not found

Tags: java, editor, atom-editor

I am using Atom.io as the IDE in my mac and java is compiling fine. But when cmd+i run it says class not found.But when there are compile errors it is telling that there are compile errors. Attaching the screenshot. Package is there dont worry. I also wanted to know if there is debugging support in Atom.

I have script installed, Please guide. I think I have to set up some environment variables in my mac, but I dont know how.
[image]

Comment: try run with _java Nice_ and where is your package defination?

Comment: package definition is there it is hidden.. you see the line numbers. I am an experienced java Programmer